# python programming with multiple functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program that asks the user to enter two colors and then display the resulting color. This is what I have so far:

```
#Define function that prompts user to enter data
def ask():
    color1=input('Enter name of first primary color:')
    color2=input('Enter name of second primary color:')
    mixColors(color1,color2)
#Write function that displays the different color combinations
def mixColors(color1,color2):
    if color1==red and color2==blue:
        print('Mixing red and blue, you get purple.')
    elif color1==blue and color2==red:
        print('Mixing blue andred, you get purple.')
    elif color1==red and color2==yellow:
        print('Mixing red and yellow, you get orange.')
    elif color1==yellow and color2==red:
        print('Mixing yellow and red, you get orange.')
    elif color1==blue and color2==yellow:
        print('Mixing blue and yellow you get green.')
    elif color1==yellow and color2==blue:
        print('Mixing yellow and blue, you get green.')
    else:
        print("I don't know what you get by mixing", color1,'and',color2,'.')
ask()
```

When I run the program, this error message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Lin/Documents/Spring Semester 2013/Computer Programming/yuan_linCh0405", line 23, in <module>
    ask()
  File "/Users/Lin/Documents/Spring Semester 2013/Computer Programming/yuan_linCh0405", line 6, in ask
    mixColors(color1,color2)
  File "/Users/Lin/Documents/Spring Semester 2013/Computer Programming/yuan_linCh0405", line 9, in mixColors
    if color1==red and color2==blue:
NameError: global name 'red' is not defined
```

Comment: You should use a dictionary with keys ('red','blue'), ('blue','red'),('red','yellow'), etc

Comment: If you use frozensets as the keys you can reduce the number of items in your dictionary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Python, strings have to be enclosed with single or double quotes (`'` or `"`). Otherwise they will be treated as variables.

In this case, `red` is neither a variable nor a string. Since `red` is not a string, Python searches for `red` in the current namespace, parent namespace and the global namespace. But the variable `red` is NOT found in any of them. So, it gives up and throws that error message.

So, all the if conditions should have been

```
if color1=="red" and color2=="blue":
...
elif color1=="blue" and color2=="red":
...
elif color1=="red" and color2=="yellow":
...
elif color1=="yellow" and color2=="red":
...
elif color1=="blue" and color2=="yellow":
...
elif color1=="yellow" and color2=="blue":
...
```